Need some help in getting correct comparison result for shock scenarios
I am working on a file in which i have three columns starting with scenario [+100, +25, -25, -100, Implied, EBA up, EBA Down] then rate index[GL-AUD-AONIA-01D, GL-INR-01D] then rates with next 5 year dates in monthly format.
my concern is say if for a particular rate index the implied or base shock scenario rate is say 5.00 then in case of +100 shock scenario it should be implied rate + 100 bps means 5 + 1 = 6.00 but in case the file which i am loading to pandas dataframe has a different rate say 9.00 against +100 shock scenario then it should mark it as false in comparison file which is not happening.infact what the code is doing instead of recalculating the rate for all the scenarios barring implied scenario it simply adding/subtracting the value in bps from the existing rate against that scenario rather using implied rate +- shock
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def apply_scenario(rate, scenario, rate_index):
    if 'Implied' in scenario:
        return rate  # Implied scenario does not modify the rate
    elif '+100' in scenario:
        # Apply +100 shock
        return rate + 1 
    elif '+25' in scenario:
        # Apply +25 shock
        return rate + 0.25
    elif '-100' in scenario:
        # Apply -100 shock
        return rate - 1
    elif 'EBA up' in scenario:
        # Apply EBA up shock
        currency = rate_index.split('-')[1]
        shock_value = get_shock_value(currency)
        return rate + shock_value
    elif 'EBA down' in scenario:
        # Apply EBA down shock
        currency = rate_index.split('-')[1]
        shock_value = get_shock_value(currency)
        # Ensure it doesn't go below -1%
        new_rate = rate - shock_value
        return max(new_rate, -0.01)
    elif 'Static' in scenario:
        # Static scenario, return the same rate
        return rate
    else:
        # Handle unknown scenarios
        return None

def get_shock_value(currency):
    # Define shock values per currency
    shock_values = {
        'ARS': 400, 'AUD': 350, 'BRL': 400, 'CAD': 250, 'CHF': 150,
        'CNY': 300, 'EUR': 250, 'GBP': 300, 'HKD': 200, 'IDR': 400,
        'INR': 350, 'JPY': 100, 'KRW': 250, 'MXN': 400, 'RUB': 400,
        'SAR': 300, 'SEK': 300, 'SGD': 150, 'TRY': 400, 'USD': 200,
        'ZAR': 350
    }
    # Return shock value for the given currency
    return shock_values.get(currency, 0)

def process_excel_data(file_path, sheet_name, output_file):
    # Load data from Excel
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=sheet_name, header=5)  # Adjust header as needed
    
    # Rename 'Forecast with timestamp' column to 'Scenario'
    df = df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: 'Scenario', df.columns[1]: 'Rate Index'})
    df['Scenario'] = df['Scenario'].str.split('/').str[1]
    
    # Initialize an empty DataFrame to store calculated rates
    calculated_rates_df = df.copy()
    
    # Iterate through each row in the DataFrame
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        scenario = row['Scenario']  # Fetch scenario from the DataFrame
        rate_index = row['Rate Index']  # Fetch rate index from the DataFrame
        
        
        # Iterate through each date column starting from the third column
        for column in df.columns[2:]:
            t0_rate = row[column]
            if pd.notna(t0_rate):
                # Calculate the rate for the scenario
                calculated_rate = apply_scenario(t0_rate, scenario, rate_index)
                if calculated_rate is not None:
                    # Update the calculated rate in the DataFrame
                    calculated_rates_df.at[index, column] = calculated_rate
    
    # Comparison DataFrame for True/False comparison
    comparison_results = (np.abs(df.iloc[:, 2:] - calculated_rates_df.iloc[:, 2:]) < 1e-10).astype(int)
    
    # Create Excel writer
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
    
    
    with pd.ExcelWriter(output_file_path, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
        # Write each DataFrame to a different sheet
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Original Data', index=False)
        calculated_rates_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Calculated Rates', index=False)
        comparison_results.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Result', index=False)
   

# Example usage:
file_path = "C:\\Users\\45320750\\Desktop\\Rate_index\\MF.xlsx"
sheet_name = 'Market Forecast Rate Indexes'
output_file_path = 'C:\\Users\\45320750\\Desktop\\Rate_index\\Market Forecast_comparison.xlsx'
process_excel_data(file_path, sheet_name,output_file)

Input
|Scenario|      Rate Index  |     30/06/2024| 31/07/2024  |
|+100   | GL-AUD-AONIA-01D  |    5.5 |6.2|
|-100   | GL-AUD-AONIA-01D  |    4 |4.2|
|Implied| GL-AUD-AONIA-01D|   5| 5.2|
|EBA up| GL-AUD-AONIA-01D | 8.5 |8.7|
Correct Calculated_rates
|Scenario|      Rate Index  |     30/06/2024|31/07/2024|  |
|+100   | GL-AUD-AONIA-01D  |    6 |6.2|
|-100   | GL-AUD-AONIA-01D  |    4 |4.2|
|Implied| GL-AUD-AONIA-01D|   5 |5.2|
|EBA up| GL-AUD-AONIA-01D | 8.5|8.7|
what my code is calculating
|Scenario|      Rate Index  |     30/06/2024  |  30/07/2024|
|+100   | GL-AUD-AONIA-01D  |    6.5 |6.8|
|-100   | GL-AUD-AONIA-01D  |    4 |4.2|
|Implied| GL-AUD-AONIA-01D|   5|5.2|
Basically the code is apply a shock of +1 bps against +100 shock scenario on top of the existing +100 rate i.e. 5.5 +1 = 6.5 which is incorrect, it should be implied rate + 1 bps shock so 5+1 = 6
and in case of scenario like EBA up and down it should give shock based on the currency value which i have defined in the code so if rate index is GL-AUD-AONIA-01D that means it is AUD based curve and for AUD ccy the shock value is 350 bps so if the implied rate is 5  , then eba up rate would be 5 + 3.5 = 8.5

You are much more likely to get an answer if you add a reproducable dataframe to your question.

My suggestion is apply a little pre-processing to your dataframe.
Suppose your original dataframe is given by:
d = {'Scenario': ['+100', '-100','Implied','EBA up'], 
 'Rate Index': ['GL-AUD-AONIA-01D','GL-AUD-AONIA-01D','GL-AUD-AONIA-01D','GL-AUD-AONIA-01D' ],
 '30/06/2024':[5.5,4,5,8.5],
 '31/07/2024':[6.2,4.2,5.2,8.7]}

original_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

Preprocessing:
# Melt dates to one column
new_df = original_df.melt(id_vars=['Scenario','Rate Index'], var_name='DATE',value_name ='Rate')

# Getting implied rates and date
implied_rates = new_df.loc[new_df['Scenario'].str.contains('Implied'), ['DATE','Rate']]

# Rename 'Rate' to 'Implied Rate'
implied_rates.rename({'Rate': 'Implied Rate'}, axis=1, inplace=True)

# Merging implied_rate to original_df 
new_df = new_df.merge(implied_rates,on='DATE',how='right')

After these operations your dataframe will look like this:
Scenario        Rate Index        DATE         Rate          Implied Rate
+100            GL-AUD-AONIA-01D  30/06/2024   5.5           5.0
-100            GL-AUD-AONIA-01D  30/06/2024   4.0           5.0
Implied         GL-AUD-AONIA-01D  30/06/2024   5.0           5.0
EBA up          GL-AUD-AONIA-01D  30/06/2024   8.5           5.0
+100            GL-AUD-AONIA-01D  31/07/2024   6.2           5.2
-100            GL-AUD-AONIA-01D  31/07/2024   4.2           5.2
Implied         GL-AUD-AONIA-01D  31/07/2024   5.2           5.2
EBA up          GL-AUD-AONIA-01D  31/07/2024   8.7           5.2

Thus, in your code, you can use implicit rate wherever you want.
Note: I created a 'DATE' field to allow groupping of implicit and non-implied rates.

Thanks Nelson for looking into it but I don't have just one date column, I have 60 dates column on monthly basis like 30/6/2024 then 31/7/2024 then 31/08/2024 and so on

@Atulsanwal, see edited code.

its not working as intended in case of multiple rate indexes and 60 dates

My goal is to give you a solution to separate implicit rates from non-implied rates.
You must test my preprocessing suggestion with appropriate changes on your code.
